# Iterate through a list of links using splinter

Tags: python, splinter

Using splinter, how can I iterate through a list of links collected using the find feature and click on each one in sequence?

Splinter is finding the links for each element with the name "store" in it using the find feature:

```
browser.find_link_by_partial_href('/store/')
```

How can I then pass each index to `browser.click` to access each link in sequence?

Answer (score 2):

```
links = browser.find_link_by_partial_href('/store/')
for link in links:
    link.click()
```